# RazorGenerator add footer on every pdf page

Tags: .net, pdf, footer, razorgenerator

I am using RazorGenerator in .NET to convert HTML pages to PDF files. This works great! I ran into a problem. When you use a `table` in your HTML with a `thead` it will repeat this `thead` on every PDF page. This is great, but now I would like to add a footer on every page as well. With a footer I mean something like you see in Word: "Page 1 of 6" or a date.

Comment: what library do you use for PDF generation?

Comment: @WiebeTijsma OpenHtmlToPdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use `<tfood>` this will repeat the HTML inside of it on every page. Example:

```
<tfood>
  <tr>
    <td>
     This text will appear on every page!
    </td>
  </tr>
</tfood>
```